# On which character table is 'A' assigned to the value of 17?

Tags: c

I've been messing with turning characters into integers and I wrote this function to do that. (I know that Unicode could break this code but let's assume we won't use any unicode characters here.)

```
int ctoint( char fCHAR ) {
        int cVALUE = fCHAR-'0';
        return cVALUE;
}
```

When I insert character 'A' to this function, it will return '17', when I insert 'B', 18 ... 'Z' 42 etc. So, what does C take reference when it is converting chars into integers when using this kind of code?
Thanks in advance :3

Edit: I tried it with some symbols and it returned -5 for a '+', -3 for a '-', -6 for a '*' and -1 for a '/'.

Edit 2: It seems like the it decrements 48 from the ASCII value of that character. '65-48' is 17 so that is an A and '43-48' is -5 which is + as I tried it in the previous edit. Does anyone know, why 48? I guess because it is the start of numbers so numbers' characters will get the value of themselves (e.g. 48-48 is 0)

Edit 3: Thank you all!!!

Comment: Look for an ascii table.

Comment: @luk2302 I did but on an ascii table, A is assinged a value of 65, not 17.

Comment: @tindomieru yep... and you subtract `'0'`. So check what `'0'` is in the ascii table. And then do 65 - that value .... did you get 17?

Comment: 65 - 48 = 17 with 48 being '0'

Comment: "Does anyone know, why 48?" For no specific reason... those that made the ascii table values just happened to put `0` there... but rhey could have placed it anywhere... it doesn't matter

Comment: @Calculuswhiz No, actually I used the conversion method -'0' without knowing how it worked so this was a weird question. I got it now. Thanksss ^w^

Comment: A `char` to `int` converter could be as simple as `int char_to_int(char c){ return (int)c;}`. It is not clear why your code is using ASCII `0` (48) to convert 'A' (65) to be equal in value to ASCII 'DC1`  (17), then calling it a `char` to `int` converter.  It might be useful however to recognize that `'0'` - `48` == `0` (and so on for all ASCII numeric characters through `9`).   i.e. `'9'` - `48` ==`9`.

Comment: @4386427 https://www.guidodiepen.nl/2017/03/clever-bit-tricks-with-ascii/

Comment: @ryyker thank you for your comment, actually because of my mistake i couldn't get int(c) method working but now i can do it simply. thanks!!! :3

Answer (score 3):

In ASCII, `'0'` has code 48 and `'A'` has code 65, which is why `'A'-'0'` evaluates to 17. See the full [ASCII table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters).